# Inserting an object to an already created entity (ManyToOne and OneToMany)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following problem which already I have two days since I am trying to solve by reading and watching tutorials but still something I am doing wrong.

I have the following two classes : Building and Group. Each building belongs to a group and only one, a group can have many buildings. So i have :

```
public class Building {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;
}
```

and

```
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Building> buildings = new ArrayList<>();
```

The idea is that first I'm creating the Group and the JSON will be something like this :

```
{
    "id": "be489e30-ebde-4cb4-bef3-5ff9b4463e4d",
    "officialName": "official",
    "shortName": "short",
    "email": "emai@example.com",
    "groupAddress": {
      "id": "15eea366-e2f0-4b38-a7b1-a9a006ef1284",
      "street": "street example",
      "number": "55",
      "town": "example town",
      "country": "example country"
    },
    "administrator": {
      "id": "0bfee30b-96d7-4e5d-9fcc-3a4f82c31301",
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "phone": null,
      "email": "emai@example.com",
      "password": "administrator"
    },
    "president": {
      "id": "293e5efe-d07e-428e-9147-87510c7255f1",
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "phone": null,
      "email": "emai@example.com",
      "password": "president"
    },
    "censor": {
      "id": "34faca46-7ce9-4842-9ddd-3116ed05e9ab",
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "phone": null,
      "email": "emai@example.com",
      "password": "censor"
    },
    "picture": "picture.jpg",
    "buildings": [
      
    ],
    "iban": "1111 0000 5555 6666 9999"
  }
```

As you can see, the Group has an Address (object), President, Administrator, Censor, all objects which I will insert them at a later stage, this is working because is @OneToOne relation and I find it easy.

At a later stage, I have the possibility to add a building to a certain group. This happens from front end by using React. So I have :

```
    const [group, setGroup] = useState({});

    const [building, setBuilding] = useState({
        address : {
            street : "",
            number : "",
            town : "",
            country : "",
            buildingName : "",
            entrance : ""
        }
    })


   useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/group/${groupId}`)
            .then(response => {
                setGroup(response.data);
            })
    }, [groupId])
```

First I fetch the group info. All good until now.

The I have some input and I am completing the address of the building

```
address : {
            street : "",
            number : "",
            town : "",
            country : "",
            buildingName : "",
            entrance : ""
        }
```

Then I handle the submit :

```
        const handleSubmit =(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post(`/api/building`, building)
            .then(() => {
                alert("Successfully added a new building")
            })
    }
```

Then I have the JSON for the current building :

```
{
    "id": "56b1d638-1fda-493e-95b4-9c6c86595552",
    "group": null,
    "address": {
      "id": "4ab5d267-f5a5-4830-bf60-fd688b893a5c",
      "street": "Example Street",
      "number": "15",
      "town": "example town",
      "country": "country",
      "buildingName": "1A",
      "entrance": "5"
    },
    "noticeBoard": null
  }
```

So far so good, I have a brand new building, the building has an address.

The question is, having in mind that I already have the group info, how can I insert this group to the current building ?

I have tried something like this :

1. 1st try : I added an empty "group : {}" to the React Hook with the idea of populating it with the known info. The result is that will generate a new group with a new id and I don't want this.

```
        const [building, setBuilding] = useState({
        group : {
          },
        address : {
            street : "",
            number : "",
            town : "",
            country : "",
            buildingName : "",
            entrance : ""
        }
    })
    const s = {...building}
    s.group = group
    setBuilding(s);
```

2. 2nd try : I've went to the back end and tried to add a new rest route :

I have the group info from the id (the id i have it in the path)
I'm creating a new Building object
I'm using the setter of the building to add the group to it
To the repository I am trying to save the new created building

This will give an infinite loop

```
    @GetMapping("/update/{id}")
    public List<Building> update(@PathVariable UUID id){
       
        Group group = groupRepository.getOne(id);
        Building building = new Building();

        building.setGroup(group);

        buildingRepository.save(building);

        return buildingRepository.findAll();
    }
```

and the JSON response :

```
{
        "id": "516f5caf-b869-4a1c-863d-adc6e9ec1e56",
        "group": {
            "id": "b083c3b9-df18-4444-a815-52150ca911b8",
            "officialName": "example name",
            "shortName": "example name",
            "email": "example@yahoo.com",
            "groupAddress": {
                "id": "ec12742a-2c2f-4c74-a30e-5d096a4478cb",
                "street": "street name",
                "number": "15",
                "town": "example town",
                "country": "example country"
            },
            "administrator": {
                "id": "18275548-a7b5-4e20-bdad-52887c0ea28f",
                "firstName": null,
                "lastName": null,
                "phone": null,
                "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                "password": "administrator"
            },
            "president": {
                "id": "8d26060e-43a5-4a8c-a4f2-4164627dda0e",
                "firstName": null,
                "lastName": null,
                "phone": null,
                "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                "password": "president"
            },
            "censor": {
                "id": "5d4dffaa-54d3-4d52-86e1-55df2160f32b",
                "firstName": null,
                "lastName": null,
                "phone": null,
                "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                "password": "censor"
            },
            "picture": "jpeg",
            "buildings": [
                {
                    "id": "516f5caf-b869-4a1c-863d-adc6e9ec1e56",
                    "group": {
                        "id": "b083c3b9-df18-4444-a815-52150ca911b8",
                        "officialName": "example name",
                        "shortName": "example name",
                        "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                        "groupAddress": {
                            "id": "ec12742a-2c2f-4c74-a30e-5d096a4478cb",
                            "street": "street name",
                            "number": "15",
                            "town": "example town",
                            "country": "example country"
                        },
                        "administrator": {
                            "id": "18275548-a7b5-4e20-bdad-52887c0ea28f",
                            "firstName": null,
                            "lastName": null,
                            "phone": null,
                            "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                            "password": "administrator"
                        },
                        "president": {
                            "id": "8d26060e-43a5-4a8c-a4f2-4164627dda0e",
                            "firstName": null,
                            "lastName": null,
                            "phone": null,
                            "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                            "password": "president"
                        },
                        "censor": {
                            "id": "5d4dffaa-54d3-4d52-86e1-55df2160f32b",
                            "firstName": null,
                            "lastName": null,
                            "phone": null,
                            "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                            "password": "censor"
                        },
                        "picture": "jpeg",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "id": "516f5caf-b869-4a1c-863d-adc6e9ec1e56",
                                "group": {
                                    "id": "b083c3b9-df18-4444-a815-52150ca911b8",
                                    "officialName": "example name",
                                    "shortName": "example name",
                                    "email": "example@yahoo.com",
                                    "groupAddress": {
                                        "id": "ec12742a-2c2f-4c74-a30e-5d096a4478cb",
                                        "street": "street name",
                                        "number": "15",
                                        "town": "example town",
                                        "country": "example country"
                                    },etc
```

3. 3rd try : I've tried to request the body of the building from frontend (@RequestBody Building building) where I already have the address with the idea just to add the group to it

```
    @GetMapping("/update/{id}")
    public List<Building> update(@PathVariable UUID id, @RequestBody Building building){

        Group group = groupRepository.getOne(id);

        building.setGroup(group);

        List<Building> buildings = Collections.singletonList(building);
        group.setBuildings(buildings);
        groupRepository.save(group);

        return buildingRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Is giving an error.

In this moment I am confused, I tried a lot but I don't know where to look anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are heading into the right direction on your solution number 2.

You just need to add `@JsonBackReference` annotation on your `buildings` field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonBackReference
private List<Building> buildings = new ArrayList<>();
```

and `@JsonManagedReference` annotation on your `group` field:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
@JsonManagedReference
private Group group;
```

`@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally. `@JsonBackReference` is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization. Using those annotations handles circular dependencies during serialization and will prevent stackoverflow error (infinite loop) from occurring.